# MVC5 Models outside of area EF6

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5, model

I am trying to call a public virtual into a Asset.cs to link data on the ModelID.

My issue is that the Model.cs is outside of the area of where the asset.cs is.

How do i link the two tables models together when they are separated by areas ?

**Assets.cs** in a area, using "model" is an issue in the public virtual because it cant find it in the Area.

```
    namespace Assets.Areas.Company.Models
     {
      public class Asset
      {
        [Key]
        public int AssetID { get; set; }
        public int ModelID { get; set; }
        public virtual Model ModelName { get; set; }
```

**Model.cs** outside the area

```
     namespace Assets.Models
     {
       public class Model
     {

    [Key]
    public int ModelID { get; set; }
    public int AssetAssignmentID { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [StringLength(100, MinimumLength = 2)]
    public string ModelName { get; set; }
```

I have tried a viewmodel approach but it just adds the fields to the asset table rather than foreign keys when i use **public virtual ModelVM ModelName { get; set; }**

I have tried using the **using Assets.Models;** to link to the model.cs when looking at **public virtual Model ModelName { get; set; }** , but when updating the table an object named 'models' is already in the database.

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. What does *separated by areas* mean? The sentence *using "model" is an issue in the public virtual because it cant find it in the Area* is incomprehensible. Also, you don't show the code that causes the errors you describe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found i can you models outside of an area, with:

```
using Assets.Models;
```

My EF Migration was causing me the issue with "**object named 'models' is already in the database.**"   This was because the table Models was already there!